# Printing nodes field value

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to print nodes field value in Drupal 7 PHP block but when i'm using the code:

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  if ($node = node_load(arg(1))) {
    if ($node->type == 'offer') {
      $company_name = check_plain($node->field_company[0]['value']);
    }
  }
  if (!empty($company_name)) {
    print $company_name;
  }
}
?>
```

it does nothing - nothing prints. I'm sure that my variable is empty, but why? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: note that instead of that horrible arg checking and node_load you can use menu_get_object(). if ($node = menu_get_object()) debug($node); to see whether the type is indeed offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$company_name = check_plain($node->field_company[0]['value']);
```

That's sooo D6. :) In D7, by default it would be:

```
$company_name = check_plain($node->field_company[$node->language][0]['value']);
```

Generally, just print_r/var_dump (or kpr/dpr if you have devel installed) $node object there to see what fields you have inside and how to access them.

Comment: Thanks. Also `$company_name = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_company'); print $company_name[0]['value'];` works, but Your idea is more efficient. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the snippet: by changing `'und'` to `$node->language`. Also, even if you are adamant on using the 'no language', you want the `LANGUAGE_NONE` constant not the value of it.

Comment: I've also found it's helpful to to check that the variables are set, such as this: `if(isset($node) && $node->field_company){$company_name = check_plain($node->field_company[$node->language][0]['value']);}`

Comment: @bdanin Much easier to do and better looking would be just if (!empty($node->field_company[$node->language][0]['value'])) - this will take care of all the cases, even if $node is not set.

Comment: Still, the best way for something like this would be just to use entity metadata wrapper: https://www.drupal.org/node/1021556